# Thread Closing Automatically After Sometimes in java

Tags: java, multithreading, background

I am using a Thread in java by extending  Thread. This Thread continuously performing some background work. But after some time (about 15mints) thread is automatically closing and the program is crashing. any please help how to create a  long run thread in java which performs some background functions and the thread must keep alive till the application is alive. But my problem is that my thread is closing even before my application shutdowns.

Best Regards,
AlenLee MJ

```
> Exception Coming:Execution protection violation
> #
> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> #
> #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x1000cb77, pid=1028, tid=11996
> #
> # JRE version: 7.0_10-b18
> # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
> # Problematic frame:
> # C  0x1000cb77
> #
> # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
> #
> # An error report file with more information is saved as:
> # E:\alen_project\QrCodeScanningAppForCCD\hs_err_pid1028.log
> #
> # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
> # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
> #
```

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace or something else showing why the thread closes?

Comment: in addition to @mthmulders, u also should post some code from in your thread.

Comment: I am using jmyron to acces the webcam.It is a thread that runs outside JVM. Along with that i am also using a normal thread.This normal thread is always looking whether a camera is available or  camera unpluged from the system so that i can print a message that camera not found or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The thread should not shut down while it has any work to do. You probably miss something and your thread stops because of an unhandled exception, memory leak or something.

Answer (score 0):

there must be some problem in the code.
u can use isAlive() method of thread to see if the thread is still alive or dead.

a thread can only be killed if it completes its execution or throws a runtime exception.

please post the exception trace if you seek more clarification on the topic.
you can use sleep(int) method or while loop with flags to keep a thread explicitly alive if yo u want though not a nice idea.

it might be a case that your main method starts thread and then completes its execution. this will happen as both are separate processes.

you can use myThreadReference.join() method in main so as to make main method wait until your thread completes execution and then possibly red some variables/data populated by the thread in your main !